# Docker コンテナ上の CentOS で iptables を実行するとエラーが発生する

Tags: centos, docker, iptables

```
# iptables -L
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/4.9.184-linuxkit/modules.dep: No such file or directory
iptables v1.4.7: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

このようなエラーがでます。
iptablesをアンインストール後、再度インストールしましたが、ダメでした。

環境 docker内にcentos6を立てています

```
>docker -v
Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea

>cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.10 (Final)

cat /proc/version 
Linux version 4.9.184-linuxkit (root@a8c33e955a82) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Alpine 8.3.0) ) #1 SMP Tue Jul 2 22:58:16 UTC 2019

iptables --version
iptables v1.4.7
```

iptablesの設定です

```
>vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [388:275634]
:RH-Firewall-1-INPUT - [0:0]
:SERVICE - [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

なぜ、firewallが設定できないのでしょうか？
ご教示お願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

docker run に `--cap-add=NET_ADMIN` オプションを付けてみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます